# Swapping out Facelets templates breaks phase listeners

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The title really sucks but I can't find a more concise one.

I have my app that contains really one JSF page using Primefaces and JSF 2.x.  I'm using the Primefaces Layout tag to construct a header, footer, navigation, and content.  Pretty simple stuff.  The navigation is using a PF Tree component that when I click on a node, the content displays for that node.  I use render= for all of the possible content.  Currently, each content is included so I could make the main page easier to read.  The content is data table that displays the records returned from the database and selecting each of them displays the values for that selection.  Think of it as Layout inside of a Layout.  The inner layout contains a datatable and then the panel grid to view the data selected.  I can add, update, and delete with no issues.

My issue is I tried to use Facelets to include the content dynamically instead of resorting to setting render=.  The code to do that is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="inc-templates/main-template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="centerContent">
        <ui:include src="/#{UtilBean.contentPage}.xhtml"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The UtilBean sets the contentPage when the node in the tree is clicked.  I have 2 nodes right now - graphic messages and email templates.

graphicMessage.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
                <p:layout id="graphicMessageLayout"
                          style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
                    <p:layoutUnit id="gmDataTableLU" position="west" size="270"
                                  header="Graphic Messages" closable="false" collapsible="true"
                                  resizable="true">
                        <h:form id="dataTableForm">
                            <p:dataTable id="gmDataTable" var="graphicMessage"
                                         value="#{GraphicMessageBean.graphicMessages}"
                                         paginatorPosition="bottom" widgetVar="gmDataTableVar"
                                         rowKey="#{graphicMessage.graphicMessageUID}"
                                         selection="#{GraphicMessageBean.selectedGraphicMessage}"
                                         selectionMode="single"
                                         style="background: #5d8bba !important; color: white !important;">
                                <pe:paginator
                                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                        pageLinks="3"
                                        rows="20"/>
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":centerForm:ogrid"/>
                                <p:column id="messageId" sortBy="#{graphicMessage.messageId}"
                                          style="width: 25%; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"
                                          headerText="Message Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{graphicMessage.messageId}" style="white-space: nowrap;"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                        <h:form id="centerForm" prependId="false">
                            <div id="outerpanel"
                                 style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 50px; width: 470px">
                                <p:panelGrid id="ogrid" styleClass="gmGrid">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column colspan="2">Graphic Message Properties</p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value="Message Id:"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputText
                                                    disabled="#{GraphicMessageBean.disabled or GraphicMessageBean.update}"
                                                    value="#{GraphicMessageBean.messageId}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value="Description:"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputText disabled="#{GraphicMessageBean.disabled}"
                                                         value="#{GraphicMessageBean.description}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value="URL:"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputText disabled="#{GraphicMessageBean.disabled}"
                                                         value="#{GraphicMessageBean.graphicURL}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value="Image Source:"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{GraphicMessageBean.imageSrc}"
                                                             effect="fade"
                                                             valueChangeListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.viewImageSrc}"
                                                             disabled="#{GraphicMessageBean.disabled}">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{GraphicMessageBean.imageSrcItems}"/>
                                                <p:ajax update="imagesrc"/>
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column id="imageSrcColumn" colspan="2">
                                            <div class="imgWrap">
                                                <h:panelGroup id="imagesrc">
                                                    <h:graphicImage

                                                            value="http://localhost/media/ep2demo/banners/#{GraphicMessageBean.imageSrc}"
                                                            height="150px"/>
                                                </h:panelGroup>
                                            </div>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <f:facet name="footer">
                                        <p:row id="buttonRow">
                                            <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                                                <p:commandButton value="Add" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.add}"
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.addGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Edit" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.edit}"
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.editGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Delete" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.delete}" onstart="alert('Are you sure?');"
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.deleteGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid :dataTableForm:gmDataTable"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Update" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.update}"
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.updateGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid gmMessages"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Save" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.save}" 
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.saveGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid :dataTableForm:gmDataTable"/>
                                                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" rendered="#{GraphicMessageBean.cancel}"
                                                                 actionListener="#{GraphicMessageBean.cancelGraphicMessage}"
                                                                 update="ogrid"/>
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <p:messages id="gmMessages"/>
                            </div>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Now the client code works because if I swap out the code for graphicMessage.xhtml with just a Hello header, I can swap content with no problem.  emailTemplate is pretty much the same thing as graphicMessage.xhtml.  To make things simple, I replaced each page with just a generic Hello! text(one at a time so one page has the full content and the other has a simple Hello text) and it doesn't work.  If I swap both out with just plain text, it works.  So the issue is in the main content somehow with all of the JSF components.  I debugged the life cycle and it never gets past the first phase.

NOTE:  One last thing I did was to tear the content out piece by piece until it works and I narrowed the issue to the p:ajax tags.  Any use of them in the layout cause the life cycle to break.  I need that tag so I can populate the properties based on the row selected in the data table.  I also need it to display the image selected in the select one menu.  Any ideas?  I don't see much on the use of the PF ajax tag, and nothing I can see I'm doing wrong.  This code works if I include it and set the render attribute.

Comment: Here's the main-template.xhtml:  Dang, too big:-)  It's the main layout containing the tree, header, footer, and the content, which is templated out in the original post.

Comment: A little bit closer.  I ripped out all of the code in content and focused on the datatable and I found f:ajax works slightly better.  Better, meaning after I refresh the browser after the initial render.  Once I refresh the browser, everything works.  I don't think that will fly with the users, so I might just go back to includes...all 19 of them.  Ugh.  There's got to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: So no one has a neat way of using Facelets to dynamically swap out content?  I'll use the includes and set the rendered flag, but if I could figure out a way to dynamically swap out one page of content with the ajax tag.  If not for that ajax tag this would have worked great.  Question for BalusC, if I use ui:includes to include 30 or so content and use rendered to show the one I want, the other 29 are still in the DOM but hidden?  If this had worked then only one would have been in the DOM at any given time, correct?